# How do I pass a method or object from client to server in Java?

Tags: java, client-server

I have multiple clients and one server. Each client has a few commands at their disposal, eg:

```
public interface Command {
    public int run();
}

public class CommandOne implements Command {
    // ...
}

public class CommandTwo implements Command {
    // ...
}
```

These commands can be executed within the client (on their machine) - or they can be "passed" to the server to be executed, and then a result will be returned.

What is the simplest way of implementing both the client and server within Java?

The following are what I've come up with:

- Serialize the command, pass it to the server, have the server deserialize it, run the command and return the result. (This won't work because methods cannot be serialized.)
- Pass a the command's name (as a String) to the server, have the server run a `switch` statement, instantiate a new command of the same type, run it, and return the result. This means if I ever add a new command class, I will have to update both the client and the server.
- Serialize the necessary method logic into some structure (JSON, XML, etc.), pass it to the server, have the server deserialize it into a custom class, run the method logic, and then return the result. This seems like overkill and requires writing a DSL.

Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**

Each request must be threaded in some way - because multiple clients could communicate with the server at the same time. This is probably not an issue with the above problem, though.

Comment: Use RPC or RESTful architectures. Don't serialize your `Command` object. The server should drive the features, not the client.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was hoping there might be some way to avoid duplicating my `Command` interface (and its subclasses) on both the client and the server.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Also, the problem with the server driving the features is that, in this case, the client can run the commands locally - it's not a straight web API.

Comment: You can always make the `Command` Serializable and use an `ObjectOutputStream` to send it to the server. The server will have to have the same version of the `Command` class file to deserialize it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I mentioned that, but it won't work since methods aren't serializable. I'm not sure what I was looking for (automatic work, maybe), but your HTTP suggestion is the best one. :)

Comment: You wouldn't serialize the methods, you server has a compiled class, it knows what the methods are. You wouldn't be able to send it `new` commands though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Right, but, in that case, it's much easier to send a request to the server and instantiate a new `Command`. I was just looking for a way to avoid putting the commands on the server (since they change frequently).

Comment: That's a dangerous action. What if the client sent a `Command` to wipe the disk? That's what I meant by the server should control the available actions.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's a good point.

Comment: @Sotirios It is not possible, the "Command" must be an object already compiled on the server (The object definition "code" is not sent, only the SUID), so it is no more dangeous than any other solution that must be compiled on the server, just a different way to look at it.

Comment: Yaeh, I'm saying it would be dangerous if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to the comments in the middle, you're right of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an ugly world, the simple thing you could do is make your server expose an interface like

```
/commands?run=CommandOne
```

and pass some parameters (in body or query string) to hold command parameters.

Then use some HTTP client to submit an HTTP request to that URI. The server would instantiate and dispatch some command to execute what you wanted.

In a more structured world, you should look into RPC calls or the RESTful architectural style.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found really elegant and fun.

If you open a port and have a listener that is just waiting for a "Runnable" to come in, you can execute the run method.  The variables will all be passed over and whatever the run method does will be done.

Even a little better have a "runOnServer()" and "runOnClient()" method.  the client creates the object, passes it to the server and goes on it's way, the server executes the runOnServer() method (against the variables since they were serialized over) then the class is automatically serialized back to the client where the runOnClient() stuff is executed.

Makes it really slick to execute something on the server.

If you want to get more advanced, look into Hazlecast, it does this already.

Comment: This sounds great but I don't quite understand how the server would understand what to do in the `run` method. Wouldn't the request have to pass over some logic of some sort (as opposed to just the class variables)?

Comment: When you serialize a class, the server instantiates a new instance of that class. This means that you deploy he class to both the client and server. When the server deserializes the class it is automatically an instance of the class that sent it (and has the same data as the client and the same code in the "run" method).  I've been really tempted to make an annotation-based version of this lately...

Comment: Ah, I see. It sounds like a decent idea unless you you have a bunch of nested objects which might make everything `Serializable`. In that case, I think it's better to use Sotirios's suggestion.

Comment: If you don't wish to serialze the nested objects, use "transient" on the variable.  If you do wish to serialize the nested objects then you have to transfer them anyway.  There is one big problem with this approach that I didn't mention though.  If your object references objects on the client and server, those objects have to be deployed to both as well.  This tends to suck things in until you are just deploying the same codebase to both the client and server which is acceptable in many cases but when it's not this can be a big problem.